# Is it possible to use vector methods to shift images stored in a numpy ndarray for data augmentation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mnist

Background: This is one of the exercise problems in the text book Hands on Machine Learning by Aurelien Geron.

The question is: Write a function that can shift an MNIST image in any direction (left, right, up, down) by one pixel. Then for each image in the training set, create four shifted copies (one per direction) and add them to the training set.

My thought process:

1. I have a numpy array of size (59500, 784) in X_train (Each row is a (28,28) image). For each row of X_train:

   1. Reshape row to 28,28
   2. For each direction (up, down, left, right):

      1. Reshape to 784,0
      2. Write to empty array
2. Append the new array to X_train

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

def shift_and_append(X, n):
    x_arr = np.zeros((1, 784))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            for k in range(-1,2):
                if j!=k and j!=-k:
                    x_arr = np.append(x_arr, shift(X[i,:].reshape(28,28), [j, k]).reshape(1, 784), axis=0)
    return np.append(X, x_arr[1:,:], axis=0)

X_train_new = shift_and_append(X_train, X_train.shape[0])
y_train_new = np.append(y_train, np.repeat(y_train, 4), axis=0)
```

It takes a long time to run. I feel this is brute forcing it. Is there an efficient vector like method to achieve this?

Comment: Depends what you are "allowed" to use as building blocks; does `numpy.roll` count?

Comment: I'm not limited from using `numpy.roll`, but it seems similar to `shift` functionality wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 nested `for` loops with an `if` condition while reshaping and appending is clearly not a good idea; `numpy.roll` does the job beautifully in a vector way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train.shape
# (60000, 28, 28)

# plot an original image
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_train[0]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Let's first demonstrate the operations:

```
# one pixel down:
x_down = np.roll(x_train[0], 1, axis=0)
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_down) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# one pixel up:
x_up = np.roll(x_train[0], -1, axis=0)
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_up) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# one pixel left:
x_left = np.roll(x_train[0], -1, axis=1)
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_left) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# one pixel right:
x_right = np.roll(x_train[0], 1, axis=1)
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_right) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Having established that, we can generate, say, "right" versions of all the training images simply by

```
x_all_right = [np.roll(x, 1, axis=1) for x in x_train]
```

and similarly for the other 3 directions.

Let's confirm that the first image in `x_all_right` is indeed what we want:

```
plt.gray() 
plt.matshow(x_all_right[0]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can even avoid the last list comprehension in favor of pure Numpy code, as

```
x_all_right = np.roll(x_train, 1, axis=2)
```

which is more efficient, although slightly less intuitive (just take the respective single-image command versions and increase `axis` by 1).

Comment: Thank you, I used in full Numpy code and it took just 1.45s for four different shifts.

Comment: @shan42nd yeah! :)